# Chinese is shown as small box when using english as ui language within java application?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-paradigm, chinese-locale

For example,with in use case diagram,I input chinese "重组分析数据集" within a use case's ellipse icon,and it is shown fine,but when I "open use case details.. ","重组分析数据集" will be shown as small boxes in name text box,and if I copy these boxes into chrome's location bar,it shows as "重组分析数据集".And if I switch vp's UI language to chinese,everything shows fine.So,how to make vp shows chinese consistently when it works under English UI?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the font I chose doesn't support chinese.